# Hashingvectorizer and Multinomial naive bayes are not working together

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, text-mining

I am trying to write a twitter sentiment analysis program with `Scikit-learn` in python 2.7. OS is Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

In Vectorizing step, I want to use `Hashingvectorizer()`. To test the classifier accuracy it works fine with `LinearSVC`, `NuSVC`, `GaussianNB`, `BernoulliNB` and `LogisticRegression` classifiers, but for `MultinomialNB`, it returns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/test.py", line 310, in <module>
    classifier_rbf.fit(train_vectors, y_trainTweets)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 552, in fit
    self._count(X, Y)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 655, in _count
    raise ValueError("Input X must be non-negative")
ValueError: Input X must be non-negative
[Finished in 16.4s with exit code 1]
```

Here is the block code related to this error

```
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_trainTweets)
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(x_testTweets)

classifier_rbf = MultinomialNB()
classifier_rbf.fit(train_vectors, y_trainTweets)
prediction_rbf = classifier_rbf.predict(test_vectors)
```

Why it is happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `non_negative` argument to `True`, when initialising your vectorizer

```
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(non_negative=True)
```

Comment: in sklearn 0.19+ it should be `HashingVectorizer(alternate_sign=False)'

Answer (score 8):

If the `non_negative` argument isn't available (just like my version)

Try putting :
   `vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(alternate_sign=False)`

Answer (score 0):

non_negative  argument have been replaced with alternate_sign. so if u want `non_negative=True`, try putting `alternate_sign=False` .It will work surely.